# How can I get the newest questions in my tags in the android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I have option to get questions which are all newest or unanswered in my tags. The problem with this is that the unanswered in my tags is almost always the same questions that no one send to be able to answer and so this is not much use.

I'd much rather see the newest questions in my tags, but this doesn't seem to be an option.

Is there any way to do this? If not could one be added?

Comment: You can simply search for `[yourtag]` and select on the right of the searchfield `Newest`

Comment: but my tags might contain more than 1 tag (plus this is a a fair bit of typing on the phone interface). What i want is the same as visiting this url : http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have favourite tags set, you can simply use `intags:mine` in the searchbox and then select `Newest`.

This will only work if you have set in your profile->preferences the favourite tags.

Comment: this works, thanks. I suppose my question really is 'please could we add a shortcut for this to the dropdown'